# SQL Server : error "Only one expression can be specified in the select list ....."

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I'm trying to update a table in SQL Server so that the column `AR Classification` is updated with the case statement below. It gets stuck and says only one expression can be specified. Anybody know what's going wrong?

Code:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[FullBase]
SET [AR Classification] = 
    (
    SELECT *  
    ,CASE  
        WHEN [Revenue Type] = 'Recurring Charge' THEN 'Recurring - Spread over Invoice Period'  
        WHEN [Financial Product   Service Type] = 'Dark Fibre Service' AND ([Initial Term (Service)]   IS NULL OR [Initial Term (Service)] = 0 OR [Initial Term (Service)] = 1 OR [Initial Term (Service)]   >= 180) THEN 'One off - IRU Recognised at Delivery'    
        WHEN [Financial Product   Service Type] = 'Duct Service' AND ([Initial Term (Service)] IS NULL OR [Initial Term (Service)] = 0 OR [Initial Term (Service)] = 1 OR [Initial Term (Service)] >= 180) THEN 'One off - IRU Recognised at Delivery'  
        ELSE 'IRU - Deferred'
     END
     FROM [dbo].[FullBase]
    )
```

Comment: `SET [AR Classification]` = ***one*** column. `SELECT *` =  ***many*** columns. Which of the many columns should SQL Server use to update the target column?

Comment: Furthermore, unless `dbo.FullBase` only has one row in, you are returning multiple rows as well as multiple columns, which row do you want to use to update  `[AR Classification]`.

Comment: So I'm a bit of a newbie to SQL so I'm not sure how it works yet. I want it to essentially do what an excel spreadsheet would do and enter in a formula into that column and do it for all rows in the table. It works when I run it not trying to update the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your subquery uses the same table as the `update` table.  This is unusual.  In this case, I don't think you want a subquery at all.  This may be what you want:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[FullBase]
    SET [AR Classification] = (CASE  WHEN [Revenue Type] = 'Recurring Charge' THEN 'Recurring - Spread over Invoice Period'  
                                     WHEN [Financial Product   Service Type] = 'Dark Fibre Service' AND ([Initial Term (Service)]   IS NULL OR [Initial Term (Service)] = 0 OR [Initial Term (Service)] = 1 OR [Initial Term (Service)]   >= 180) THEN 'One off - IRU Recognised at Delivery'    
                                     WHEN [Financial Product   Service Type] = 'Duct Service' AND ([Initial Term (Service)] IS NULL OR [Initial Term (Service)] = 0 OR [Initial Term (Service)] = 1 OR [Initial Term (Service)] >= 180) THEN 'One off - IRU Recognised at Delivery'  
                                     ELSE 'IRU - Deferred'   
                               END);
```

EDIT:

Your problem involves something called "scalar subqueries".  These are subqueries that are used in a context when a single column value or constant would be expected.  In this case, you are setting a value in an `update`, so a single value is expected for the `set`.

Your query returned multiple columns (the `*`) and probably multiple rows as well.  Each of these will generate an error.

I believe the cause is a misunderstanding of how to use `update`.  You can use the other columns in a row when you are setting an `update` value.

Comment: That works perfectly! Thank you so much. May I ask what I was doing wrong for the future? Trying to learn as quickly as I can